# javascript getMonth does not works on remote server

Tags: date, tomcat, javascript-objects

Actually on a react.js+java spring project, I try to get month of a javascript Date object, created with a sql datetime retrieved value.

Locally on my wamp server i've got no trouble. But in prod environment served by a tomcat, my variable just return nothing. 
Even chrome debugger just  skip the line and seems unable to return any value, not even an undefined..

I think the problem is more about locale value but i'm not sure at all and i d'ont know how to fix it..

My code example above is the most basic usage we can do with Date object in javascript...

```js
let dateTime = new Date(sqlDateTime);
let month = dateTime.getMonth() +1;
```

Here you can see my code in chrome dev tools from remote server on the first image and on localhost on the second image

[debug on remote host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVS3v.png)

[debug on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJspu.png)

In both we can see the sql datetime well retrieved and in the  case of localhost the getMonth value is ok and in the remote case not

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Zbooby, post a snippet of your code as well so people can help you with a solution better.

Comment: I can't open the images but, could you please compare the sqlDateTimes ? May be you can use console.log().